# In Gmail In-Reply-To values are changed while replying through gmail

Tags: php, imap, gmail-imap

I have set the value for In-Reply-To to find the trail mail but while the user replying to that mail the value is changed

**Example:**

I am sending like below

> 'In-Reply-To: Testing value' ( the user also received with this text)

When user replying to this email. i have received like below

> 'In-Reply-To: <20180625100102.11363294CA@xxxxxxxxxx.com>'

Please assist me i tried so many way but it failes

**my code**

```
$to      = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: XXXXXXXXXXXXX.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: p.XXXXXXXXXXXXX.com' . "\r\n" .
'In-Reply-To:testvalue';

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Unclear what you are trying to ask. Edit the question to ask a more specifically worded question. For now, refer to: [`How do I ask a good question?`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is expected.

`In-Reply-To` is expected to be set to the `Message-Id` of the message you're replying to; it does not preserve the previous value.  So, it forms a linked-list:

- Message Z with header `In-Reply-To: Y` is in reply to message with `Message-Id: Y`.
- Message Y which will have its own `In-Reply-To: X` header referring to the message with `Message-Id: X`.
- and so on.

Since this breaks if you're missing any of the messages in the middle, the `References` header is the same idea, but more robust.  It's a list of all messages that the message is in reply-to (capped to 10, generally), and should always have the root message (the first message in the conversation) as the first item.  When you form a reply, add the `Message-Id` of the message you're replying to to the end of `References` header, and drop the second item until it is ten items long.

Also, all these are defined to be `Message-Ids`, which should be enclosed in angle brackets, like `<abc@example.com>`

Comment: Did you mean, you have set the value to message id instead of in-reply-to??

Comment: Yes; you take the `Message-Id` of the message you're replying to, and you put that in `In-Reply-To`.